# Vertical space around title

Tags: spacing, titles

I'm trying to draw horizontal lines above and below the title and adding some extra space between them and the text. I've being trying this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\title{
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{Notas en Computación Cuántica}
\vspace{1cm}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
}
\author{John Doe}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

However, the resulting document looks like both \vspace commands are adding the space only below the title, even the one that is placed right above. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to do it with the tools of the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\bigskip\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\bigskip\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\preauthor{\vspace*{10ex}\begin{center}\Large}
\postauthor{\end{center}}

\title{Notas en Computación Cuántica}
\author{John Doe}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]